# createAsyncThunk abort() behaving abnormally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, mern, redux-toolkit

I am trying to optimize my react code by fixing any memory leaks. For this i am using [createAsyncThunk canceling-while-running](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#canceling-while-running) to cancel requests in case my component unmounts. Below is my useEffect from my component

```
 useEffect(() => {
     const data = { page: curPage }
     const promise = dispatch(blockedUsers(data))
     return () => promise.abort()
 }, [curPage])
```

Below is my async thunk reducer

```
export const blockedUsers = createAsyncThunk(
  "admin/blocked",
  async (data, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await axios.get(API_URL + "/blocked");
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);
```

below is my buider for my async thunk reducer

```
.addCase(blockedUsers.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
})
.addCase(blockedUsers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.blocked.users = action.payload.result;
        state.blocked.users.length === 0
          ? (state.blocked.total = 0)
          : (state.blocked.total = action.payload.count.count);
})
.addCase(blockedUsers.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
        console.log(action);
        toast.error(
          "Could not get blocked users. Reason: " + state.message,
          unsuccessful
);
```

When my coponent loads two requests are made to the server due to react strictmode. The first request gets rejected everytime no matter what and the second one gets fullfiled.
[my dev tools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE8gl.png).

Because of this i get a toast error for rejected request but at the same time i get the required data rendered in my application.
And i get undefined error which is given below:

```
type: 'admin/blocked/rejected', payload: undefined, meta: {…}, error: {…}}
error
: 
{name: 'AbortError', message: 'Aborted'}
meta
: 
{arg: {…}, requestId: '9H3Z2GZ1_A1hBxH4Di', rejectedWithValue: false, requestStatus: 'rejected', aborted: true, …}
payload
: 
undefined
type
: 
"admin/blocked/rejected"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

I am unable to fix this. And i am not sure how will this behave once deployed. Please help. Thanks in advance.